# BizTalk orchestration hydration / rehydration issue

Tags: .net, biztalk, orchestration

I have a custom received pipeline that breaks down a large file into individual file and send them to the message box and an orchestration would subscribe to these messages and process them.  In my orchestration i have several expression shapes that executes the methods in a .net dll.  I also added logging at every step.  At any given time, the message box might be flood with hundreds of messages. What I have noticed is that some messages are execute multiple times.  I doubled checked to make sure I wasn't generating multiple message of the same.  This leads me believe that maybe it has something to do with hydration.  From what I researched, when an orchestration is hydrated, it will persist on the shape it was on and also the state of the dll.  When it resumes, it will resume at it's persisted shape and not starting from the beginning.

Have anyone seen this problem?  What test / configurations I can do to validate / correct this issue?!

[image: Here is part of the orchestrations]

[image: Here is the .net method that each of the Expression shape calls]

Many thanks!

Angie

Comment: Did you try to use "atomic" scope?

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the disassembler orchestration, and also samples of the code in the .net library you are calling.

Comment: Yes, hydration just allows BizTalk to serialize the current status of "idle" orchestrations (e.g. waiting for correlated messages, waiting for timers etc) so that the resources can be reallocated to more urgent tasks. Are you using direct binding to messagebox? Possibly there is a feedback loop somewhere?

Comment: nonnb, yes i am using direct binding from the messagebox based on the message type property that I promoted in my custom received pipeline.  I will try a dummie orchestration just to receive the message and write it out to see if the message is duplicated..

Comment: Evgeniy.. I have tried the atomic and long runing scope, still the same result.

Comment: hugh, I have uploaded a image of the orchestration and some .net methods.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Using Evgeniy's suggestion (atomic scope) should prevent hydration entirely, meaning the message duplication isn't occuring due to that. If you post messages of the same schema that you are receiving, you might be causing feedback. Try filtering the incoming message (e.g. on BTSOperation, or some adapter specific property)

Comment: i don't think it's hydration because i was monitoring the performance monitor and it's indicated no orchestration hydrated at all.  So what would cause the orchestration to kick back to the orchestration and start all over all?  Is there any filtering I can use?  The message was initially coming from a custom pipeline..

Answer (score 1):

I think you confuse hydration with persistance points. Letters combined with some try\catch logic can make an orchestration to restart from the latest persistance point. You didn't post a full picture of your orchestrations, but I see there a scope. Do you have any exception handling there?

Anyway orchestration can't post any messages to message box without explicit send shape. Also look if you have latest SPs and cumulative updates installed.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem :)

The hydration and rehydration occurs when the orchestration is idle waiting for something. Therefore, it should not happen in the middle of processing a file.

- Just to make sure that it is not a data quality issue, check that there is  no duplicate data in your input files.
- You could use the throttling features to ensure that only one file is processed at a time. This would remove one potential error source.
- The other thing that you could do is to check your error handling, do you have any retry logic when the first call fails? If Biztalk is also doing a retry, that could explain the duplication.

Comment: I think the issue is not in hydration / rehydration.  The issue may be in the direct binding from messagebox.  For some reason the orchestration kicks back the message to the messagebox and it executes from the beginning again.  I tried to create a new message and change the promoted property for the new message, and the problem still the same.  I am not sure if for some reason the orchestration kicks back the message to the MessageBox, which message will it kick back?  the original or new?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest in such case the promotion of 2 new custom properties at the pipeline stage for each new message you generate -

1) Total number of messages
2) Current message number

This way you can keep track, print or save every single message number at the beginning of the orchestration or at any other stage you decide and it can make the work easier.

Comment: when the message is somehow kicked back to the message box, does it have the same message number?

Comment: If it's the same instance of the message, then yes. And even if not, when you will try to print the message number in the orchestration, you will see it doesnt have a message number, and then it means it's a clone and did not come from the pipeline for sure and it also may help you with the investigations. I would also suggest using the performance counters, to make sure your system isnt getting into throttling state, and if it does, check what you can do to allow the system to run with enough resources and avoid that state.